# Why does using JQuery AJAX stop this promise chain from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

When I make an AJAX call with this function the value of return2 is an unfulfilled promise which is printed instantly, the then() function is not waiting for it to be fulfilled before continuing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/security/csrf`,
    type: 'POST',
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve("DONE")}, 10000)
    })
}).then((return2) => {
    console.log(return2)
})
```

However when I create a promise and resolve it then the value of result2 is "DONE" as expected after 10 seconds delay

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("HERE");
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve("DONE")}, 10000)
    })
}).then((result2) => {
    console.log(result2)
})
```

I know that the AJAX call is resolving successfully as when I run the below it logs the data out as normal and doesn't log an error

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/security/csrf`,
    type: 'POST',
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

Comment: [Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/nx397atu/). What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.8.3 I had a got at running your fiddle in the same environment as the project and still got the problem

Comment: Looks like the version was just too old, thanks for the help

Comment: OK. You would need to use `$.Deferred()` instead of new Pomise in 1.8.3 to get same result